# Using Laravel defined routes within a VUE component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 6 and VUE. I am converting a blade file into a VUE component. The blade file contains a table with rows of data being pulled in from a mysql DB. I have created a draggable component that is displaying users and will allow me to drag and drop rows in order to rearrange them, and the table is using VUE slots to pass html to my component. On my index view the table has a button on it. When the button is clicked it goes to a `/create` endpoint/route that I defined in Laravel using a routes.php file. I don't want to use vue routing, I prefer to maintain my laravel routes as they are. The issue I am having is, I do not know how to implement this exactly as I am new to VUE. Can someone shed some light on this? I tried using axios but maybe I am mis-using? Is there a better way to use a vue component but continue to use my routes I have defined in routes.php? Thank you.

main.blade.php

```
 <!-- Draggable Component -->
            <div id="app">
                <draggable table=@yield('content.main')></draggable>
            </div>
```

routes.php (partial to show which endpoint I am wanting to hit)

```
  $route->any('users/create', 'UsersController@create');
```

Draggable.vue

```
<template>
    <section v-bind:table="table">
        <button class="btn btn-default" @click="create()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
        <slot></slot>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       props: ['table'],
       data() {
           return {
               draggable: '',
           };
       },
       created() {
           this.draggable = this.table;
       },
       methods: {
           create() {
               axios.get(this.endpoint, {
                   UserName: this.UserName
               }).then(res => {
                   this.creating = true;
                   this.UserName = res.data.UserName
               }).catch(err => {
                   console.log("Error: " + err);
               })
           },
       },
       computed: {
           endpoint() {
               return `users/create`;
           },
       }
   };
</script>
```

The error I get when the button is clicked:

```
 Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Comment: If you want to use vue with your laravel route then, combine the blade and the vue.

Comment: Hi @JesusErwinSuarez can you please elaborate? Or provide an example or point me to the correct docs? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `endpoint()` you can add `window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host` so the method would be

```
endpoint() {
    return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + 'users/create';
},
```

Comment: I added this in my endpoint method. The page is not redirecting to the /create page though?? In my browser console I do receive a 200 response and in the preview tab within the Network tab, the /create page is displayed. But in the actual browser itself, no REDIRECT is happening so the pages are not changing... why is this?

Comment: OK just to be clear, what do you want is when you press the create button you need to be redirected to `/users/create` and fetching data from this endpoint ?

Comment: Sorry if I am confusing. What I want is: when the button is clicked, I want to just redirect to the /create page.

Comment: Ok in this scenario you don't need the `axios` call as you not fetching any data, you need to use `window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + 'users/create';` and i think you can do it inline also.

Comment: Where would I place this within my Draggable.vue file?

Comment: inside your `create` method add `window.location = this.endpoint();` only